# Finding Sum of Variables in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a program that requires the user to enter a number and will continue to loop until a positive number is given. When a positive number is given, it will alert the user and present them with the sum of the digits of their number. However, I thought I had written my code correctly, but it is giving me an incorrect answer. What have I done wrong and how can I fix this?

```
user_input = float(int(input("Please Enter Your Number:")))
s = 0

while user_input < 0:
  float(int(input("Please Enter Another Number: ")))
if user_input > 0:
  s += user_input%10
  user_input //= 10
  print("You've entered a positive number! The sum of the digits is: ", s)
```

Comment: What did you enter, what was the answer, and what did you expect?

Comment: I had entered 145 and expected 10, but instead got 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four things:

1. Not sure why you storing the input as `float`, `int` should suffice.
2. If you give a negative input, it will enter the `while` loop. However, in the `while` loop, you are not actually assigning the new input to `user_input`. Fix this by adding `user_input =`
3. The `while` loop guarantees `user_input` is >= 0, so `if user_input > 0:` is unnecessary.
4. Probably the most important, to calculate the sum of digits, you need to repeatedly divide and sum, not just do it once. So, add a `while` loop.

Final code:

```
user_input = int(input("Please Enter Your Number: "))
s = 0

while user_input < 0:
    user_input = int(input("Please Enter Another Number: "))

while user_input:
    s += user_input % 10
    user_input //= 10

print("You've entered a positive number! The sum of the digits is: ", s)
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I really appreciate the feedback!

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please kindly accept it. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is generally used to decide if something should be done *once.*

If you want to keep going until `user_input` becomes zero, you'll need a `while`.

Also, I'm not entirely certain why you're storing the number as a `float`, especially when you make that from an `int` anyway. It may as well just be an `int`.

Additionally, you're loop to re-enter the value if it was negative doesn't actually *assign* the new value to the variable.

And you probably also want to outdent the `print` statement lest it be done on every iteration of the loop you're about to add.

---

Of course, some may suggest a more *Pythonic* way of summing the digits of a positive number is a simple:

```
sum([int(ch) for ch in str(x)])
```

That works just as well, without having to worry about explicit loops.

Comment: @DeepakSaini, I think you'll find `user_input //= 10` *does* modify it.

Comment: @paxdiablo I think Deepak means here: `while user_input < 0: float(int(input("Please Enter Another Number: ")))`

Comment: I stand corrected. Apologies. Will add that. Of course, that just makes it closer to Tomothy's answer so I'd suggest just upvoting that, since it already has a head start.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is using assert and a function:

```
def sum_num():
    # try get user input
    try:
        user_in = input('Enter Number: ')
        assert int(user_in) > 0

    except AssertionError:
        # we got invalid input
        sum_num()

    else:
        s_d = sum([int(i) for i in user_in])

        print('You\'ve entered a positive number! The sum of the digits is: ', s_d)

#run the function
sum_num()
```

So this will asked user input, if it is not greater than zero it will throw assertion error, which we catch and return the user to inputting the number by calling the function again. If all is well, we split the  input into character and add them up. as list('12') gives ['1','2']. We convert to int and add them. :)

The awesome thing about this is you can add more too the asset to capture other issue as floats, character as invalid inputs. E.g.

Assuming literal_eval is important( from ast import literal_eval)

```
assert isinstance(literal_eval(user_in),int) and int(user_in)>0
```

Check if user_in is integer and it is greater than 0. So you won’t get issues when user inputs floats or characters.